# android (sendintent) on sms send sms

Tags: android

I can't find an example of [`SmsManager.sendTextMessage()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/gsm/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)
use of the sending intent anyway. I wanna make sure my sms was sent, retry up to 3 times if it's not. Can someone provide me with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude [first example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/SmsMessagingDemo.html) and [second example](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android)